# Python script runs correctly in terminal gives error when run via crontab

Tags: python, macos, cron, bluetooth-lowenergy, python-asyncio

I have written a short python script that uses bleak and asyncio to control a bluetooth LE device. The script works exactly as intended when I run it manually in pycharm or terminal, however I want to run it at specific intervals using crontab.

I've searched for a solution and tried adding absolute paths as well as logging errors. I have found that the script throws an error when run from crontab but I don't quite understand how to fix it.

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from bleak import BleakClient
import asyncio

address = "DFB18A2C-6BAB-439E-AF05-485FB4259B75"
MODEL_NBR_UUID = "99FA0002-338A-1024-8A49-009C0215F78A"

async def main(address):
    async with BleakClient(address) as client:
        for i in range(3):
            await client.write_gatt_char(MODEL_NBR_UUID, bytes.fromhex("0800"))
            time.sleep(0.5)

asyncio.run(main(address))
```

And here is the error from crontab log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/emileberhard/PycharmProjects/BedMove/main.py", line 19, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main(address))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/emileberhard/PycharmProjects/BedMove/main.py", line 13, in main
    async with BleakClient(address) as client:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bleak/backends/client.py", line 61, in __aenter__
    await self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bleak/backends/corebluetooth/client.py", line 78, in connect
    device = await BleakScannerCoreBluetooth.find_device_by_address(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bleak/backends/scanner.py", line 220, in find_device_by_address
    return await cls.find_device_by_filter(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bleak/backends/scanner.py", line 249, in find_device_by_filter
    async with cls(detection_callback=apply_filter, **kwargs):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bleak/backends/corebluetooth/scanner.py", line 44, in __init__
    self._manager = CentralManagerDelegate.alloc().init()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bleak/backends/corebluetooth/CentralManagerDelegate.py", line 88, in init
    raise BleakError("Bluetooth device is turned off")
bleak.exc.BleakError: Bluetooth device is turned off
Exception ignored in: <CentralManagerDelegate objective-c instance 0x0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bleak/backends/corebluetooth/CentralManagerDelegate.py", line 102, in __del__
IndexError: NSRangeException - Cannot remove an observer <CentralManagerDelegate 0x7fd036fbe0b0> for the key path "isScanning" from <CBCentralManager 0x600000aab100> because it is not registered as an observer.
Exception ignored in: <function CentralManagerDelegate.__del__ at 0x7fd01863cca0>
```

I'm running MacOS btw!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to run the command as root (sudo)

Comment: `0 0 * * * sudo python script_here.py >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen thanks for the reply! I tried adding sudo but now it says this in the log: 
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required

Comment: you might need to add a password to it, read the sudo docs

Comment: figured it out! but still getting same error when putting the command in sudo crontab :(

Answer (score 0):

remove that command from your cronjob.

do this, select your editor of choice from the list.

```
sudo crontab -e
```

then add your cronjob, exit and then save (these will run as root)

```
0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /users/emileberhard/PycharmProjects/BedMove/main.py >> /users/emileberhard/out2.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: While OP is debugging their crontab, they probably don't want `>/dev/null 2>&1` since that will hide any error messages. It would be better to send it to a file where it can be inspected. Though I agree this solution can be appropriate once it all works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested solution but it's not working for me. My crontab now looks like this: `emileberhard@Emils-MacBook-Air ~ % sudo crontab -l`

`0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /Users/emileberhard/PycharmProjects/BedMove/main.py >> /Users/emileberhard/out2.txt 2>&1`

Comment: are you sure its `/Users/` and not `/users/` in your paths?

Comment: also run `whereis python` and use that path as the executable in the cron script

Comment: Yes I'm sure it's /Users/! I have put the path in but it still doesn't work. Same error as before.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have bluetooth off on your OSX device.